# table of contents for new command (lecture notes)

Tags: table-of-contents

Please find the working example

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \setlength{\textheight}{23cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} \setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm} \setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip} \hoffset=-1.4cm \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage[mathscr]{eucal} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage[all]{xy} \usepackage{lineno} \usepackage{epsfig} \usepackage{amscd} \usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{hyperref} \usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} \usepackage[thinc]{esdiff} %\usepackage[all]{xy} \usepackage{tikz-cd} \usepackage[normalem]{ulem} \newcommand{\ms}{\medskip} \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{-1.7} \newcommand{\toto}{\rightrightarrows}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{lecnum} \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thelecnum-\arabic{page}} \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thelecnum.\arabic{section}} \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thelecnum.\arabic{equation}} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thelecnum.\arabic{figure}} \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thelecnum.\arabic{table}}

% % The following macro is used to generate the header. % \newcommand{\lecture}[4]{     \pagestyle{myheadings}  \thispagestyle{plain}   \newpage    \setcounter{lecnum}{#1}     \setcounter{page}{1}    \noindent   \begin{center}      \framebox{          \vbox{\vspace{2mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {\bf MT2223: Real analysis-I
                        \hfill Jan-May 2022} }
                \vspace{4mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {\Large \hfill \bf Lecture #1   \hfill} }
                \vspace{2mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {Date: #2 \hfill  Course instructor: Praphulla Koushik} }
                \vspace{2mm}}       }   \end{center}    \markboth{Lecture #1: #2}{Lecture #1: #2}    } % % Convention for citations is authors' initials followed by the year. % For example, to cite a paper by Leighton and Maggs you would type % \cite{LM89}, and to cite a paper by Strassen you would type \cite{S69}. % (To avoid bibliography problems, for now we redefine the \cite command.) % Also commands that create a suitable format for the reference list. \renewcommand{\cite}[1]{[#1]} \def\beginrefs{\begin{list}%        {[\arabic{equation}]}{\usecounter{equation}             \setlength{\leftmargin}{2.0truecm}\setlength{\labelsep}{0.4truecm}%             \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.6truecm}}}    \def\endrefs{\end{list}} \def\bibentry#1{\item[\hbox{[#1]}]}

%Use this command for a figure; it puts a figure in wherever you want it. %usage: \fig{NUMBER}{SPACE-IN-INCHES}{CAPTION} \newcommand{\fig}[3]{  \vspace{#2}     \begin{center}      Figure \thelecnum.#1:~#3    \end{center} } % Use these for theorems, lemmas, proofs, etc.

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[lecnum] \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma} \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} \newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim} \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary} \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example} \newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise} \newtheorem{construction}[theorem]{Construction} \newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question} \newtheorem*{note}{Note}

\linenumbers

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal} \newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb} \newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak} \newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow} \newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow} \newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}
 


\def\og{\leavevmode\raise.3ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\langle\!\langle$~}} \def\fg{\leavevmode\raise.3ex\hbox{~$\!\scriptscriptstyle\,\rangle\!\rangle$}}

\begin{document}        \title  {Real analysis I}
            \author[Praphulla Koushik]{Praphulla Koushik}       \today  \maketitle  \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} 
            {\bf Note}: {\it LaTeX template courtesy of UC Berkeley EECS dept.}
            {\bf Disclaimer}: {\it These notes have not been subjected to the       usual scrutiny reserved for formal publications.  They may be distributed       outside this class only with the permission of the Instructor.}
            \lecture{1}{today}123    \end{document}
```

I copied the template from [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/template.tex](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eggordon/10725-F12/template.tex) and made some small changes to get the above example.

I want to get table of contents that is based on the lectures. If I write \tableofcontents, it is giving nothing.

Please let me know how to get it.

Comment: Please also let me know if there are any outdated commands in the code..

Comment: Please see the updated answer adding address and email information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** after follow-up question.

Since you want to produce a document with a collection of lectures with a corresponding list (of lectures), one approach is to use the class `article` and the `tocloft` package to define a list of lectures.

It was defined the macro `\lecture` with two parameters `\lecture{<id number>}{<date>}` to format the heading of each lecture.

[image: x]

[image: y]

[image: d]

[image: b]

The course name, the semester and the instructor name are loaded outside of the macro using:

```
\newcommand{\CourseName}{MT2223: Real analysis-I} 
\newcommand{\CourseSemester}{Jan-May 2022}  
\newcommand{\CourseInstructor}{Praphulla Koushik}
```

The way to add address and email information in the `article` class is to place them after the author name separated by `\\` like

```
\author{Praphulla Koushik\\[10pt] 
Department of Mathematics\\ Some University \\ Some place\\[10pt]% add address and mail here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\href{mailto:praphullakoushik123@someuniversity.edu}{praphullakoushik123@someuniversity.edu}\\[10pt]
My Academic Page:\ \url{https://myacademicpage.com} % other information
}
```

This is the complete code.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tocloft} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only to add dummy tex <<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff} 
  
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,breaklinks]{hyperref} % changed <<<<<<
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} 

%%******************************************************************** Changed 
\newcommand{\CourseName}{MT2223: Real analysis-I} % fill <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\CourseSemester}{Jan-May 2022}  % fill <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\CourseInstructor}{Praphulla Koushik}    % fill <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newcommand{\listlecturename}{List of Lectures \hfill {\footnotesize Page \par}} % title of the list <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newlistof[chapter]{lecture}{lec}{\listlecturename} % define list of lectures

\newcounter{lecnum}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thelecnum-\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thelecnum.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thelecnum.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thelecnum.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thelecnum.\arabic{table}}

\newcommand{\lecture}[2]{% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< use as  \lecture{number}{date}
    \pagestyle{myheadings}
    \newpage
    \setcounter{lecnum}{#1}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \refstepcounter{lecture}
    \addcontentsline{lec}{lecture}{Lecture~#1:~#2}
    \noindent
    \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
        \centering\vspace{2mm}
        {\bfseries\CourseName \hfill \CourseSemester
         \vspace{4mm}\\ 
         \Large \hfill  Lecture #1  \hfill }
         \vspace{4mm}\\  
         {\normalfont Date: #2 \hfill  Course instructor:~\CourseInstructor}
         \vspace{2mm}
    \end{minipage}
    } % end fbox
    \markboth{Lecture #1: #2}{Lecture #1: #2}
    \setcounter{section}{0}% reset counters
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
                } % end lecture
%%********************************************************************  

\begin{document}    
\title{Real analysis I}
\author{Praphulla Koushik\\[10pt] 
Department of Mathematics\\ Some University \\ Some place\\[10pt]% add address and mail here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\href{mailto:praphullakoushik123@someuniversity.edu}{praphullakoushik123@someuniversity.edu}\\[10pt]
My Academic Page:\ \url{https://myacademicpage.com} % other information
}
\date{\today}    
\maketitle 
\vfill
\noindent\textbf{Note}: \emph{\textit LaTeX template courtesy of the Department of Mathematics of Some University.}

\noindent\textbf{Disclaimer}: \emph{These notes have not been subjected to the usual scrutiny reserved for formal publications.  They may be distribute  outside this class only with the permission of the Instructor.}      
\thispagestyle{empty}     
\newpage         

\listoflecture % list of lectures
\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage

\lecture{1}{February 21}
\section{Introduction}
1. \kant[1]

\lecture{2}{April 1\textsuperscript{st}}
\section{Numbers}
2. \kant[2]

\lecture{3}{July 4\textsuperscript{th}}
\section{Functions}
3. \kant[3-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks.. It is working.. Was there any other changes made?

Comment: One small problem is, with lectures I am not able to use \address \email thing. Can this also be fixed?

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik  Where do you want to put your address and email ? In the title page?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this portion: Use it wisely.

```
% % The following macro is used to generate the header. 
% \newcommand{\lecture}[4]{     \pagestyle{myheadings}  \thispagestyle{plain}   \newpage    \setcounter{lecnum}{#1}     \setcounter{page}{1}    \noindent   \begin{center}      \framebox{          \vbox{\vspace{2mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {\bf MT2223: Real analysis-I
                        \hfill Jan-May 2022} }
                \vspace{4mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {\Large \hfill \bf Lecture #1   \hfill} }
                \vspace{2mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {Date: #2 \hfill  Course instructor: Praphulla Koushik} }
                \vspace{2mm}}       }   \end{center}    \markboth{Lecture #1: #2}{Lecture #1: #2}    }
```

Either you comment the whole thing or not.

**Try this to use this macro:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \setlength{\textheight}{23cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} \setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm} \setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip} \hoffset=-1.4cm \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage[mathscr]{eucal} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage[all]{xy} \usepackage{lineno} \usepackage{epsfig} \usepackage{amscd} \usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{hyperref} \usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} \usepackage[thinc]{esdiff} %\usepackage[all]{xy} \usepackage{tikz-cd} \usepackage[normalem]{ulem} \newcommand{\ms}{\medskip} \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{-1.7} \newcommand{\toto}{\rightrightarrows}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{lecnum} \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thelecnum-\arabic{page}} \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thelecnum.\arabic{section}} \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thelecnum.\arabic{equation}} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thelecnum.\arabic{figure}} \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thelecnum.\arabic{table}}

% % The following macro is used to generate the header. 
 \newcommand{\lecture}[4]{     \pagestyle{myheadings}  \thispagestyle{plain}   \newpage    \setcounter{lecnum}{#1}     \setcounter{page}{1}    \noindent   \begin{center}      \framebox{          \vbox{\vspace{2mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {\bf MT2223: Real analysis-I
                        \hfill Jan-May 2022} }
                \vspace{4mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {\Large \hfill \bf Lecture #1   \hfill} }
                \vspace{2mm}
                \hbox to 6.28in { {Date: #2 \hfill  Course instructor: Praphulla Koushik} }
                \vspace{2mm}}       }   \end{center}    \markboth{Lecture #1: #2}{Lecture #1: #2}    } % % Convention for citations is authors' initials followed by the year. % For example, to cite a paper by Leighton and Maggs you would type % \cite{LM89}, and to cite a paper by Strassen you would type \cite{S69}. % (To avoid bibliography problems, for now we redefine the \cite command.) % Also commands that create a suitable format for the reference list. \renewcommand{\cite}[1]{[#1]} \def\beginrefs{\begin{list}%        {[\arabic{equation}]}{\usecounter{equation}             \setlength{\leftmargin}{2.0truecm}\setlength{\labelsep}{0.4truecm}%             \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.6truecm}}}    \def\endrefs{\end{list}} \def\bibentry#1{\item[\hbox{[#1]}]}

%Use this command for a figure; it puts a figure in wherever you want it. %usage: \fig{NUMBER}{SPACE-IN-INCHES}{CAPTION} \newcommand{\fig}[3]{  \vspace{#2}     \begin{center}      Figure \thelecnum.#1:~#3    \end{center} } % Use these for theorems, lemmas, proofs, etc.

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[lecnum] \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma} \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} \newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim} \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary} \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example} \newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise} \newtheorem{construction}[theorem]{Construction} \newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question} \newtheorem*{note}{Note}

\linenumbers

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal} \newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb} \newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak} \newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow} \newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow} \newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}
 


\def\og{\leavevmode\raise.3ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\langle\!\langle$~}} \def\fg{\leavevmode\raise.3ex\hbox{~$\!\scriptscriptstyle\,\rangle\!\rangle$}}

\begin{document}        \title  {Real analysis I}
            \author[Praphulla Koushik]{Praphulla Koushik}       \today  \maketitle  \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} 
            {\bf Note}: {\it LaTeX template courtesy of UC Berkeley EECS dept.}
            {\bf Disclaimer}: {\it These notes have not been subjected to the       usual scrutiny reserved for formal publications.  They may be distributed       outside this class only with the permission of the Instructor.}
            \lecture{1}{today}123    \end{document}
```

**Avoid this to suppress this macro:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \setlength{\textheight}{23cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{16cm} \setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm} \setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip} \hoffset=-1.4cm \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage[mathscr]{eucal} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage[all]{xy} \usepackage{lineno} \usepackage{epsfig} \usepackage{amscd} \usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{hyperref} \usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} \usepackage[thinc]{esdiff} %\usepackage[all]{xy} \usepackage{tikz-cd} \usepackage[normalem]{ulem} \newcommand{\ms}{\medskip} \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{-1.7} \newcommand{\toto}{\rightrightarrows}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{lecnum} \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thelecnum-\arabic{page}} \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thelecnum.\arabic{section}} \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thelecnum.\arabic{equation}} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thelecnum.\arabic{figure}} \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thelecnum.\arabic{table}}

% % The following macro is used to generate the header. 
% \newcommand{\lecture}[4]{     \pagestyle{myheadings}  \thispagestyle{plain}   \newpage    \setcounter{lecnum}{#1}     \setcounter{page}{1}    \noindent   \begin{center}      \framebox{          \vbox{\vspace{2mm}
                %\hbox to 6.28in { {\bf MT2223: Real analysis-I
                        %\hfill Jan-May 2022} }
                %\vspace{4mm}
                %\hbox to 6.28in { {\Large \hfill \bf Lecture #1   \hfill} }
                %\vspace{2mm}
               % \hbox to 6.28in { {Date: #2 \hfill  Course instructor: Praphulla Koushik} }
               % \vspace{2mm}}       }   \end{center}    \markboth{Lecture #1: #2}{Lecture #1: #2}    } % % Convention for citations is authors' initials followed by the year. % For example, to cite a paper by Leighton and Maggs you would type % \cite{LM89}, and to cite a paper by Strassen you would type \cite{S69}. % (To avoid bibliography problems, for now we redefine the \cite command.) % Also commands that create a suitable format for the reference list. \renewcommand{\cite}[1]{[#1]} \def\beginrefs{\begin{list}%        {[\arabic{equation}]}{\usecounter{equation}             \setlength{\leftmargin}{2.0truecm}\setlength{\labelsep}{0.4truecm}%             \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.6truecm}}}    \def\endrefs{\end{list}} \def\bibentry#1{\item[\hbox{[#1]}]}

%Use this command for a figure; it puts a figure in wherever you want it. %usage: \fig{NUMBER}{SPACE-IN-INCHES}{CAPTION} \newcommand{\fig}[3]{  \vspace{#2}     \begin{center}      Figure \thelecnum.#1:~#3    \end{center} } % Use these for theorems, lemmas, proofs, etc.

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[lecnum] \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma} \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} \newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim} \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary} \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example} \newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise} \newtheorem{construction}[theorem]{Construction} \newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question} \newtheorem*{note}{Note}

\linenumbers

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal} \newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb} \newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak} \newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow} \newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow} \newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}
 


\def\og{\leavevmode\raise.3ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\langle\!\langle$~}} \def\fg{\leavevmode\raise.3ex\hbox{~$\!\scriptscriptstyle\,\rangle\!\rangle$}}

\begin{document}        \title  {Real analysis I}
            \author[Praphulla Koushik]{Praphulla Koushik}       \today  \maketitle  \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} 
            {\bf Note}: {\it LaTeX template courtesy of UC Berkeley EECS dept.}
            {\bf Disclaimer}: {\it These notes have not been subjected to the       usual scrutiny reserved for formal publications.  They may be distributed       outside this class only with the permission of the Instructor.}
            %\lecture{1}{today}123    
            \end{document}
```

In this case you cannot use this command: `%\lecture{1}{today}123`.

Comment: Did you happen to remove the tikzcd ? If I use the first one it says "Environment tikzcd undefined"

Comment: This does not seem to do anything :O No table of contents appearing after using \tableofcontents